# Using columns as references

Tags: sql, oracle, reference

everyone.

My question is, if I'm using a column with SUM or COUNT in my SQL, for exemple:

```
Select ITEM, sum(PRICE), count(ITEM), (<column2>/<column3>)... from TABLE..
```

Is there a way to use the columns as references?

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a subquery or CTE:

```
WITH t as (
      Select ITEM, sum(PRICE) as price, count(ITEM) as cnt
      from TABLE..
     )
SELECT item, price, cnt, price / cnt
FROM t;
```

You can also repeat the expressions.  Or, in your particular case, just use `AVG()`:

```
      Select ITEM, SUM(PRICE) as price, count(ITEM) as cnt, AVG(PRICE)
      from TABLE..
```

Comment: I was using subquerys (but in this case, I wanted to avoid using it), and now that you pointed out, the AVG function can really help me out is this situation. Thanks for the answer =)